# How to pass std::string_view by value or by const reference

Tags: c++17, string-view

Usually `string_view` is used for function parameters like this:

```
void fval(std::string_view sv);
void fcref(std::string_view const &sv);
```

Which is better?

const reference is 8 bytes and `string_view` is usually twice that, e.g. 16 bytes.

However, if not inlined or optimized away, const reference might have two indirections - one for the ref, second for the pointer inside.

How STL doing it?

Comment: Interestingly, why downvote, without comment? I can elaborate at least 1h about both way.

Comment: One down, three up. (I wouldn't call it a trend yet but...) ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We usually pass `string_view`s by value.

Examples from the C++20 draft:

- [Formatting](http://eel.is/c++draft/format.functions)
- [Time Zone Lookup](http://eel.is/c++draft/time.zone.db.access)

Comment: I was about to ask who is "we" :) Thanks Marshall !

Comment: Some explanation for why this is might be nice :)